# Building a "floating" platform

Tags: mounting

I am planning to build a "floating" platform that needs to be able to hold at least 200kg (440 lb), the problem is, I can't attach it to three walls, as there is an exit on the third wall. My question is: is this possible, or would it have to have a pillar on the unsupported corner?
Here is a birds eye view with dimensions[image: Drawing badly scanned in]
Thanks,
Ben

EDIT: It's basically a floating bed, strain wise.

Comment: Where is the load going to be? On the far corner? In the center? Spread? Is it static load?

Comment: The load is not static, and should be able to put up and taken down multiple times a day.

Comment: Are you putting any cross braces in? What is the top and/or bottom surface material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't need to have a pillar. *Would* need at least a diagonal brace securely mounted to the wall framing. Unless, that is, you can build a boxed platform rigid enough to carry that stress without flex.

I'd use 3-5 heavy duty brackets like this.You'd barely be able to see them under your platform, leaving it with a floating appearance. Leave the end one 20-40cm from the end to help hide it visually.

I've built several such surfaces with good results using 2-1/2" lag screws. The brackets should ideally reach about 2/3 the way to the front or could be extended with structural top rails.

[image]

This question comes along regularly in various forms. Here are a few.

[How can I support a desk without legs or brackets](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49153/how-can-i-support-a-desk-without-legs-or-brackets)

[How can I mount a desk on a wall with L-brackets?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27261/how-can-i-mount-a-desk-on-a-wall-with-l-brackets)

[How is a floating desk top supported against the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29182/how-is-a-floating-desk-top-supported-against-the-wall)

[DIY Floating Desk in New Build Home](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/66834/diy-floating-desk-in-new-build-home)

[What is the ideal method of supporting a 27" deep floating desk across 10 feet of wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114905/what-is-the-ideal-method-of-supporting-a-27-deep-floating-desk-across-10-feet-o)

Comment: Thanks, Do lag screws work in aerated concrete, or would I use some sort of heavy duty wall anchors? Also would [this](https://www.fischer.co.uk/en-gb/products/high-performance-steel-anchors/aircrete-anchor-fpx-i) work?

Comment: I haven't worked with aerated concrete, but I'd guess that anchor would work fine. You must use some sort of expanding anchor, as concrete screws alone wouldn't have enough bite.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor that corner to the ceiling with some cable and eye bolts.